# Ember.js framework usable without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Without Node.js installed in a developer machine, is Ember.js still usable, at least to be able to develop and test ember app on local machine? Or Ember framework is totally dependent on Node.js?

**Update:**

My point is not about the documentation, I just want to ask why it cannot work without node.js isn't Javascript frameworks run in the Browser, why should it be dependent on things like Node.js? Example jQuery runs without node, why Ember cannot work the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you build an Ember.js app the resulting app does NOT depend on Node.js. You can run it in the browser without any server code (ie. using static hosting to serve the html/js/css files), or you can choose any backend server you wish (eg. php, C#, java, python, ruby, etc...).

However, the Ember-cli tool DOES depend on Node.js. This tool is very useful to quickly generate code (and tests), build the code, and test it.  In fact, I'm not sure if there is a way to build current Ember version projects without it.

As @locks said, you can use an older version which does not use the Ember-cli tool, but it would come with many disadvantages and really you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ember CLI is the officially supported way to develop Ember applications. Ember CLI is a development toolkit that helps you generate projects and addons, use the addon ecosystem, setup a testing harness, run a development server, and build your project.

At the moment you can still develop globals-style applications by downloading the releases [off of the builds page](http://emberjs.com/builds/) and then managing the build pipeline yourself. I do **not** recommend this as it will be stop being supported.